# java: question on filter and servlet mapping

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a web application with the following structure:

```
TOMCAT_HOME
  |
   webapps
     |_myapp
          |-html/
          |-various directories
          |-WEB-INF/
          |-index.html
```

The application has various servlets that are registered over various paths.
The application itself can be accessed via `http://IP:PORT/myapp/`
This of courses causes to get the `index.html` (in the welcome list).
My question is, how would I register a filter for specifically the access of the root directory but **not** the subdirectories i.e. the url-mapping **not** to be `/*`
If I place as url-pattern `/` seems not to work.
So the filter would intercept only this request `http://IP:PORT/myapp/` and not `http://IP:PORT/myapp/path` or `http://IP:PORT/myapp/servlet/path`.
Additionally the filter would intercept a request like `http://IP:PORT/myapp/index.html` which is equivalent to the one I aim.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily test for `/` and do your thing, otherwise let it pass through. With a `/*` URL pattern.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res,FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException,ServletException{

    HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest)req;
    String path=request.getServletPath();

    if(path.equals("/") || path.equals("/index.html"){
        // do your thing
    }

    chain.doFilter(req,res);
}
```

Comment: That is how I do it now, but I do not want to hardcode string comparisons of the paths in the code.Would like to do it via configuration if possible

Comment: @user: In that case you should configure an init parameter in your `web.xml` and retrieve it from the `ServletContext` which you can get from the `FilterConfig` object passed into the `init()` method.

Comment: Sorry I do not follow:what parameter to pass?The path?

Comment: Any of the values you wish to pass into your application from web.xml should be an init parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Why not set the filter as `/index.html` then? It will not cause your subdirectories to be filtered.